# I need to choose a sub-matrix from a matrix with minimal difference with unitary results

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab, I have a matrix X with size e.g.,  12 x 17,   I need to select an 12 x 12 sub-matrix  from it Y such that the sum of column and rows of the matrix Y is minimum into the sum of columns and rows of the matrix eye(12), which can be explained in matlab as follows:  `sum(sum(abs(Y))) - sum(sum(eye(12)))`. I want only to select 12 columns out of 17, it's not necessary to change the rows locations. It means I need only to choose 12 columns from X with my condition.

I couldn't understand how to start doing that program.

Comment: We can't understand how to start either without more context. Show us some code snippets, and perhaps explain what that `sum` equation is, so that it's easier to help.

Comment: @DanPollard I modified the question, the sum is the summation of the matrix. foe example, if we have the matrix Y, the  sum(sum(Y)) is the sum of columns first and then sum of the rows. We use the expression in matlab to find the sum of a matrix.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html), you can call `sum(Y, 'all')` which sums every element of a matrix. This will be more efficient than calling 'sum' twice. Also, `sum(sum(eye(12))) = 12` as `eye` just produces an identity matrix.

Comment: @DanPollard Yes, exactly.